# How to redirect a 501 status code from IBM Liberty to an error page?

Tags: http-headers, websphere-liberty

Have IBM Liberty set up, and some deliberately corrupt requests which arrive receive a `501 Not Implemented` response.

Sample corrupt request:

```
TRACK /<script>alert('TRACK');</script> HTTP/1.1
Referer: ...
Accept: */*
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Host: ...
...
```

The response sent by Liberty is a default, which has the context of:

```
HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
... headers omitted ...
Date: Tue, 01 Feb 2022 01:01:01 GMT
Content-Length: 92

Error 501: Method TRACK is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API
```

Instead of presenting a 501 and the above message to the requester, **I want to direct the requester to a custom error page with a simple message of my choosing**; at worst a plain HTML file.

I have not yet found a way to get IBM Liberty to produce anything other than the above for a 501 Not Implemented response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that by defining error pages for your application. Here is how I configured that:

- create your error page - error.html
- create following entry in `web.xml`

  ```
  <error-page>
     <error-code>501</error-code>
     <location>/error.html</location>
  </error-page>
  ```

Whenever your app would generate 501 it will return your error.html page instead.

Tested using Postman and your `Track` method. First got 501 unimplemented, then error page.

Make sure you have `servlet-x.y` and `jsp-a.b` features in your `server.xml`